# Unity, Volume Slider Problem When Changing Scence

Tags: unity-game-engine

im making a game that have a empty game object for audio source (music) and the script for that music, and i also have a volume slider in diffrent object . 
The Script :

```
float musicVolume = 1f;

private void Update()
{
    mainMusic.volume = musicVolume; 
}

// Slider will Trigger This 
public void SetVolume(float volume)
{
      musicVolume = volume;
}
```

i use that way because it's simple and easy since i will only use 1 music. 
With that i can control my music volume correctly, but the problem is when i go to another scence and go back, the slider seems don't do anything so my music volume won't cahange.
So how to i fix it? 
Sorry for my bad english. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

**First Of All you can remove Volume initialize From Update Method**

**Your Problem**

> When Set Volume From Slider It's Okk set Success Like 0.5f
>   But After Call Update Methos So Your Volume Set 1f from musicVolume variable

**Solution**

> remove Volume initialize From Update Method

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the object having the AudioSource is destroied as soon as a new scene is loaded.

Go with this in its script in order to avoid its deallocation when you change the scene:

```
void Awake () {
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
}
```

As a side note, your Update could be avoided because setting the volume at each frame is not optimal.

Answer (score -1):

why not simply

```c#
public void SetVolume(float volume)
{ 
    mainMusic.volume = volume; 
}
```

without the `Update` in between? Do the work only when it is needed!

---

To your question: it sounds like you are using `DontDestroyOnLoad` on the `mainMusic` and loosing the reference due to destroying the duplicate after loading the scene. You should get an exception about that!

However, simply search for the AudioSource in your script like

```c#
private void Start()
{
    mainMusic = FindObjectOfType<AudioSource>();
}  

public void SetVolume(...){ ... }
```

or if there are multiple `AudioSource`s in your Scene give the main source an explicit type like e.g.

```c#
public MainAudioSource : AudioSource
{
   // Does nothing but now you can explicitely search for it
}
```

and then in the other script do

```c#
private void Start()
{
    mainMusic = FindObjectOfType<MainAudioSource>();
}
```